# Crear variable de entorno en un script usando dockerfile

Tags: bash, docker, shell, shell-script

Estoy intentando crear una variable de entorno SETTINGS en una imagen de Python utilizando un Dockerfile. Esta variable, tiene que ser dinámica, es decir, que pueda cambiar entre el perfil de "production" y "preproduction" una vez la imagen esté creada.

Para ello he creado un script (entrypoint.sh) que realiza dos acciones, crear la variable SETTINGS y ejecutar una línea de python.

El problema es que la línea de python se ejecuta bien pero la variable SETTINGS no se crea.

Script

```
#!/bin/bash
profile=$profile
export SETTINGS=/acalls-service/${profile}.cfg
python -m "_acalls_clasiffier" 
exec
```

Dockerfile

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-c", ". entrypoint.sh"]
```

He probado tanto con ["./entrypoint.sh], como con la orden de arriba y más opciones.

Comment: Podrías usar [ENV en el Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env)

Comment: @PabloLozano esto no lo haría dinámico ya que cogería el valor del profile en el momento de crear la imagen solo

Comment: si usas ARG podrías hacerlo dinámico

Comment: en el `docker run` puedes pasar variables de entorno con el flag `-e`